# SteelToe not able to access data from config server

Tags: c#, configuration, steeltoe

I have following the `SteelToe` documentation for accessing configuration data from my config server. https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-configuration/#2-2-5-access-configuration-data

Inside my `TestController` I setup the configuration global variable in the constructor. However when I check the variable `_config` it has no value basically `null` value.

I not sure if I need to physically map the values to the `CustomConfig` class properties? As this is not specified in the documentations.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class CustomConfig { 
     public string Message { get; set; } 
}

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
          .AddConfiguration(configuration)
          .AddCloudFoundry()
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();

     this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.Configure<CustomConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("spring:cloud:config:uri"));
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
   }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .AddConfigServer()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
     private Startup.CustomConfig _config;     
     public TestController(IOptions<Startup.CustomConfig> configSettings)
     {
          _config = configSettings.value; // this is null
     }
}
```

Comment: When/how is ConfigureServices called?

Comment: @Jonny am not sure what you mean? It's part of the startup class.

Comment: But I don't see any reference to that method in your code. Are you sure it's called? Add a breakpoint and debug just to be sure. I might be missing something or you haven't included the call in your code snippets above.

Comment: @Jonny the method gets called by the runtime. I have stepped into the code when the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things happening here that are in your way:

1. Don't build configuration inside Startup, that should be handled in program.cs
2. Property names need to match up when binding config to custom classes
3. Options should be configured in [`Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#general-options-configuration)

Comment: Did that get you to a resolution, or is there more that isn't working for you? I didn't get into anything with Spring Cloud Server for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems the only way to solve my issue is as follows:

The `CustomConfig` class is extended to have a constructor and inside this constructor I get the value of the `uri` from config server

```
public class CustomConfig
{
    public string uri { get; set; }

    public CustomConfig(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        uri = configuration.GetValue<string>("spring:cloud:config:uri");
    }
}
```

And then inside my Controller I call the class within the constructor as follows:

```
private Startup.CustomConfig _customConfig;

public TestController(Startup.CustomConfig customConfig)
{
    _customConfig = customConfig;
}
```

When I check the `_customConfig` variable it consist my `uri` value.

I wont mark this as an Answer and will await others suggestion.